# You have gotten/got addicted to sugar by drinking too much cola last week - meaning "You are addicted to sugar right now"?

Tags: meaning, tense, present-perfect

**Example 1**

> What happened to me?

> What has happened to me?

In Examples 1, I want to mean, "right now, I feel something different about myself.

**Example 2**

> You got addicted to sugar by drinking too much cola last week.

> You have gotten addicted to sugar by drinking too much cola last week.

In Examples 2, I want to mean, "right now, you are addicted to sugar because you drank too much sugar last week.

---

I know that the present perfect tense can make it sound more relevant to the present.

However, I wonder whether past tense can have that effect, too.

Comment: Your first example probably isn't helpful, because *contextually* it's virtually certain both Simple Past and Present Perfect refer to something ***recent*** (which causes you to ask the question in the first place). Feasibly the Simple Past version might be asking about something that happened long ago, but that's just not very likely. For the *second* pair, the Simple Past version is "agnostic" as to whether addressee is *still* addicted, but the Present Perfect version pretty much *forces* the interpretation that addressee *is* still addicted.